# Searching for a spot clustering algorithm for 171 spots with given Long, Lat , exept K-means

Tags: algorithm, location, cluster-analysis

I need to created clusters for 171 customers located in a city for a university work on a VRP problem, have already performed K-Means clustering, need one more algorithm to try out its results. Although Long and Lat of each customer is known, as well as their distance from the depot, unfortunately we have no knowledge of the depots location . Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: If python is an option, there is a bunch of different clustering algorithms in the [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) library. Another possibility, if you know the expected clusters' sizes, is to use the [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview) library, which uses graph partitioning algorithms.

Comment: thank you very much ,Affinity Propagation algorithm is proven more than enough for my parameters.

Comment: If you have the position of the customers, along with their distances to the depots, you could use some trilateration algorithm, such as [this one}(https://github.com/lemmingapex/trilateration) to compute the position of the depots. I remember doing it for a parcel delivery optimization project, the results were more than decent, even if all we had were the travel times between customers and depots.

Comment: i will probably try this out as well depending on my professor in charge orders, thank you very much though for the advice

Answer (score 1):

For latitude and longitude, KMeans is a poor choice. Because Earth is a sphere.

At this tiny data size, use Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering, Affinity Propagation, Spectral Clustering, and k-Medoids (PAM). They all accept a *distance matrix* which zou should computer with Haversine distance, not Euclidean.

Comment: The reason we used K-means is because every customer-spot exist at the same city, so the deviation is very small to zero. For a second approach tho i started fixing an Affinity propagation algorithm. The reason for this is that my problem concerns the satisfaction of clients who all have Time_windows, so instead of a distance matrix connection i want to try out a clustering using their common Time-Windows space. Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: About haversine: if the points considered belong to roughly the same region on earth (say a max distance of 1000km would be OK), it can be worthy to translate the latitude/longitude coords into UTM coordinates, for which distance can be approximated without having to use haversine. Can be very useful for big datasets where computing haversine for the whole distance matrix takes too long.

Comment: @akallos a small region can still have a large distortion! In New York, the distortion is already 20% or so. Only close to the equator is fine. That is why projections such as UTM exist.

Comment: Will check it out today to see what i can use - retrieve from this, thank you for your advice =)